# Clone an element with an specific attribute with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to clone an element with a specific attribute that I've set via JS. The code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="test" data-test></div>
  <div class="test" data-test data-cloneable></div>
  <div class="test" data-test></div>
</div>

<div>
  <button data-tool="clone">Clone</button>
</div>
```

One of those elements have an `data-cloneable` attribute that I'm checking with JS:

**JavaScript**

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-test]");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {

 cloneTool = document.querySelector("[data-tool='clone']");
 cloneTool.onclick = function() {
   var clone = element.cloneNode(true);
   if(element.hasAttribute("data-cloneable")) {
     container.appendChild(clone);
   }
 };

});
```

It's not working, ahh, more or less, the problem is that command only clones the last element in the container and not the specific element.

Comment: Define the "specific element". Please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and specify what currently happens and what should happen instead.

Comment: The "specific element" is the element that have the `data-cloneable` attribute.

Comment: I see, but what makes that element "specific"?  Your question implies that you want to clone a specific `[data-cloneable]` but it doesn't happen. What is `element`? Your question as it is doesn't help us to understand the problem properly. Providing more context helps.

Comment: Yeah, it seems critical to ask: where is `element` defined?

Comment: OK, I've placed the rest of code in the question. Sorry!

Comment: sorry what do you mean by `cloned element may appear under its origin`

Comment: do you mean like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e7sk5qd8/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e7sk5qd8/2/

Comment: Did you try the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering the `onclick` event multiple times. It only registers the last `event` you assigned, since the last element does not have the `data-cloneable` attribute, then `element.hasAttribute("data-cloneable")` always returns `false`.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");

var cloneTool = document.querySelector("[data-tool='clone']");
    cloneTool.onclick = function() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-test][data-cloneable]");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
        var clone = element.cloneNode(true);
        container.appendChild(clone);
    });
};
```

Comment: Yeah, it works... I've learned too much with your answer! Thanks. :D

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Or do you mean that the clone would appear just under its origin?

http://jsfiddle.net/omikey/nupc7htn/2/

```
var cloneTool = document.querySelector("div[data-cloneable='true']");
cloneTool.onclick = function(clone) {
  var node = this.cloneNode(true);
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.appendChild(node);
};

<div id="container">
  <div class="test">1</div>
  <div class="test" data-cloneable="true">2</div>
  <div class="test">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code is the event registration, since you are using `onclick` property in each iteration you are overriding the previously assigned click handler.

So at the end of the loop the only handler that is present is the one corresponding to the last `data-test` element, which when triggered does not have the `data-clonable` attribute so nothing happens.

Do you mean something like

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var cloneTool = document.querySelector("[data-tool='clone']");
cloneTool.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-test][data-cloneable]");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    container.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="test" data-test>1</div>
  <div class="test" data-test data-cloneable>2</div>
  <div class="test" data-test>3</div>
</div>

<div>
  <button data-tool="clone">Clone</button>
</div>
```